# How to escape extended pathname expansion patterns in quoted expressions?

Tags: bash, escaping, design-patterns, expansion

In addition to the basic `*`, `?` and `[...]` patterns, the Bash shell provides extended pattern matching operators like `!(pattern-list)` ("match all except one of the given patterns"). The `extglob` shell option needs to be set to use them. An example:

```
~$ mkdir test ; cd test ; touch file1 file2 file3
~/test$ echo *
file1 file2 file3
~/test$ shopt -s extglob  # make sure extglob is set
~/test$ echo !(file2)
file1 file3
```

If I pass a shell expression to a program which executes it in a sub-shell, the operator causes an error. Here's a test which runs a sub-shell directly (here I'm executing from another directory to make sure expansion doesn't happen prematurely):

```
~/test$ cd ..
~$ bash -c "cd test ; echo *"
file1 file2 file3
~$ bash -c "cd test ; echo !(file2)"  # expected output: file1 file3
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `cd test ; echo !(file2)'
```

I've tried all kinds of escaping, but nothing I've come up with has worked correctly. I also suspected `extglob` is not set in a sub-shell, but that's not the case:

```
~$ bash -c "shopt -s extglob ; cd test ; echo !(file2)"
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `cd test ; echo !(file2)'
```

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ bash -O extglob -c 'echo !(file2)'
file1 file3
```

Answer (score 4):

bash parses each line before executing it, so "shopt -s extglob" won't have taken effect when bash is validating the globbing pattern syntax.  The option can't be enabled on the same line.  That's why the "bash -O extglob -c 'xyz'" solution (from Randy Proctor) works and is required.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way, if you want to avoid `eval` and you need to be able to turn *extglob* on and off within the subshell. Just put your pattern in a variable:

```
bash -c 'shopt -s extglob; cd test; patt="!(file2)"; echo $patt; shopt -u extglob; echo $patt'
```

gives this output:

```
file1 file3
!(file2)
```

demonstrating that *extglob* was set and unset. If the first `echo` had quotes around the `$patt`, it would just spit out the pattern like the second `echo` (which probably should have quotes).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't have any real experince with *extglob*, but I can get it to work by wrapping the `echo` in an `eval`:

```
$ bash -c 'shopt -s extglob ; cd  test ; eval "echo !(file2)"'
file1 file3
```