# Using bash -c and Globbing

Tags: bash, glob, gnu-parallel

I'm running gnu-parallel on a command that works fine when run from a bash shell but returns an error when parallel executes it with bash using the -c flag. I assume this has to do with the special globbing expression I'm using.

```
ls !(*site*).mol2
```

This returns successfully.

With the flag enabled the command fails

```
/bin/bash -c 'ls !(*site*).mol2'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

The manual only specifies that -c calls for bash to read the arguments for a string, am I missing something?

Edit:
I should add I need this to run from a gnu-parallel string, so the end resultant command must be runnable by /bin/bash -c "Some Command"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try the following code :

```
bash <<EOF
shopt -s extglob
ls !(*site*).mol2
EOF
```

**Explanation :**

when you run `bash -c`, you create a `subshell`, and `shopt` settings are not inherited.

**EDIT**

If you really need a one liner :

```
bash -O extglob -c 'ls !(*site*).mol2'
```

[See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529054/how-to-escape-extended-pathname-expansion-patterns-in-quoted-expressions)

Comment: You may want to use a single-quoted here document separator `bash <<'EOF'` lest the calling shell interpolates some of the special characters. Or you could stick to your original `bash -c` approach and just add `shopt -s extglob;` before any commands.

Comment: Depends of the need of the OP, but I will add something for that

Comment: @sputnick That is definitely what I want but I don't know how to add arguments to Parallel's default calling command which is /bin/bash -c ""